# Eclipse like FilteredTree for Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt (using Qt SDK with Qt Creator) and in the process of creating a GUI. What I'm looking for is a FilteredTree like the one found in the Preferences of Eclipse. Is there something "ready to use" out there? I've tried all search queries I can think of but no results so far.

In case it matters I'm absolutely willing to update to the newest Qt version.

Comment: Not sure exactly what filtering Eclipse does, but have you read up on Qt 4's "Model/View" architecture, and QSortFilterProxyModel?  Basically the same approach is used for widgets whether they're lists, tables, trees, etc.  This sample shows basic sorting and filtering: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/itemviews-basicsortfiltermodel.html

Comment: Hi, unfortunatly I still didnt have time to actually test this out. But from what I've read its what I need. thanks